# regex with replace() for letters only

Tags: javascript, regex, text, replace

I have a string that output

```
20153 Risk
```

What i am trying to achieve is getting only letters, i have achieved by getting only numbers using regular expression which is

```
const cf_regex_number = cf_input.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

this will return only `20153` . But as soon as i tried to only get letters , its returning the while string instead of **`Risk`** . i have done my research and the regular expression to get only letters is using `**/^[a-zA-Z]*$/**`

This is my line of code i tried to get only letters

```
const cf_regex_character = cf_input.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/,'')
```

but instead of returning **`Risk`** , it is returning **20153 Risk** which is the whole line of string .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first pattern is locating *every* non-digit and replacing it with nothing.

On the other hand, your second pattern is locating just the *first* occurence of a pattern, and the pattern is looking for *start of string, followed by letters, followed by end of string*. There is no such sequence - if you start from the start of string, there are exactly zero letters, and then you are left very far from the expected end of the string. Even if that worked, you are deleting letters, not non-letters.

This pattern is parallel to your first one (delete any occurence of a non-letter):

```
const cf_regex_character = cf_input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'')
```

but possibly a better way to go is to extract the desired substring, instead of deleting everything that it is not:

```
const letters = cf_input.match(/[a-z]+/i)[0];
const numbers = cf_input.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

(This is if you know there is such a substring; if you are unsure it would be better to code a bit more defensively.)

Answer (score 6):

## `/[^a-z]+/i`

- The `[` brackets `]` signify a range of characters; specifically, `a` to `z` in this case.
- Actually the `i` flag means `i`nsensitive to case, so that includes `A` to `Z` also.
- The caret `^` inverts the pattern; it means, anything not in the specified range.
- And the `+` means continue adding characters to the match as long as they are they within that range.
- Then stop matching.

In effect this matches everything up to the space   in `20153 Risk`.

Then you replace this match with the empty string `''` and what you've got left is `Risk`.

```js
const string = '20153 Risk';
const result = string.replace(/[^a-z]+/i, '');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
cf_input="20153 Risk"

const cf_regex_character = cf_input.replace(/\d+\s/,'')
console.log(cf_regex_character)
```

```js
str="20153 Risk"
reg=/[a-z]+/gi
res=str.match(reg)
console.log(res[0])
```